# Why is Assembly.LoadFrom loading a previously unloaded strongly named assembly from the GAC instead of loading from the specified path?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac

I am trying to load

System.ValueTuple Version=4.0.**3**.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

in my current app domain using Assembly.LoadFrom method by specifying the full path.

The assembly does exist at this path and it has the same version that I need, and yet, it instead ends up loading

System.ValueTuple Version=4.0.**0**.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

from the GAC.

The second one has a different build number. I know assembly probing starts from the GAC but since these assemblies are strongly named (so they all have a unique identity), shouldn't it realize that these are both different assemblies and then after failing to find it in the GAC, load it up from the specified path?

Is there a way I can force it to load from the specified path, instead of the GAC?

Comment: The two assemblies do have the same key token, though.

Comment: Turn on Fusion Logging and show us the log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net

Comment: @Dai I enabled fusion logs and checked the logs for System.ValueTuple, initially it did load the correct assembly from the specified path but then later in the logs, it said, "Version redirect found in framework config: 4.0.3.0 redirected to 4.0.0.0." and then after this it said "Switch from LoadFrom context to default context" and then loaded 4.0.0.0 from the GAC.

Where can I find this "framework config"? The logs only mentioned 2 config files: machine config at C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\framework\... and my application config. None of these have this re direct.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I think that only implies that the same ey pair was used to sign both assemblies. So, they are both coming from the same publisher. I don't think we can conclude anything else about the 2 assemblies based on just the fact that hey have same public key token.

Comment: Version redirects are so handy until they are not. There are a bunch of config files in `C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\framework\...`, (make sure you are looking at the right version and bitness folder), check out all of them. You could also use the SysInternals "Process Monitor" tool to see what files are being looked at

Comment: BTW, why not install v4.0.3.0 into the GAC?

Comment: @Flydog57 I checked the file whose path was mentioned in the fusion logs, it doesn't have any redirect. It's a file named machine.config, I couldn't find any file named framework.config

Comment: @Flydog57 Actually this code is part of a larger custom application that I am writing which needs to verify if I am including all the assemblies and their right dependencies in the installer. We don't work with the GAC.

Comment: It is talking about C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config, could be Framework64.  You'll need to find out why somebody changed it.

Comment: it's probably not loading it from the GAC, necessarily.  It is using the GAC assembly because that assembly is previously loaded by the same identity.   just use `Assembly.Load` as indicated in the docs [Assembly.LoadFrom Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-8.0) "The LoadFrom method has the following disadvantages. Consider using Load instead."

Comment: @Hans Passant Yes, that's the exact file path mentioned in fusion logs. However, I don't think anyone has ever modified this manually. Moreover, I can just post the contents of that file here, I did not find any redirect there.

Comment: @BrettCaswell As I have mentioned in the title, I did check the list of loaded modules in Debug window in VS to confirm that this assembly was not loaded until I call Assembly.LoadFrom. Fusion logs show that the loader first loads the right assembly from my path but then it finds a redirect to 4.0.0.0 in the framework config, so it then loads the assembly from GAC which has a different version. I dont know what/where can I find this framework config.